# Converting GNU makefile of one user into another user

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have a GNU makefile that compiles a set of source codes on my system and I want to give the source code to another person (different system) so, will the same GNU makefile function on his system? can it be modified to run on his system?

Comment: It would depend on what your system is and what his system is.

Comment: @AnonMail Do you mean the OS by the system?. I use Linux and the other person as well. My question is for both, Linux to Linux and Linux to Windows case.

Comment: Is there anything in the makefile that uses programs that only exist in your user account, rather than system-wide programs like `gcc`?

Comment: @jisd For Linux to Linux, it depends on what version of make each system is using, what Linux commandsthe make file is using, and also how your make file deals with file locations.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. A makefile usually contains system-specific things, such as toolchain filenames and paths.
There are tools that aim to solve this problem by "making the makefiles", in order to provide platform independance. Two such systems are CMake and GNU Autotools.

In some cases it could be possible that a makefile works directly on another system, but don't count on it.